# Function only works when I add an alert

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I am have modified some code to allow a video in a popup and the popup only gets placed to the left, right, top, or bottom properly after I put in an alert. The video plays so that's not the issue. I am assuming that the alert is buying time to get the coordinates to determine where the popup should be. It works completely fine with images and text without issue.

```
(function (diagram) { 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var diagramData = window.svgpublish.diagramData;
        $.each(diagramData, function (shapeId, shapeData) {

            var props = shapeData.Props;
            if (!props)
                return;
            var $shape = $("#" + shapeId);


            // decorate the shape with "hand" cursor
            $shape.css("cursor", "pointer");

            // hide the popover hiding when clicked outside
            $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                $shape.popover('hide');
            });

            $shape.on('click', function (evt) { 
                evt.stopPropagation();
                //***** For Clicking the icon to show the popup ********//
                //$shape.popover('toggle');

            });

            $shape.on('mouseover', function () {
                $(this).attr('filter', 'url(#hover)');
                //***** For Mousing Over the icon to show the popup ********//
                $shape.popover('show');
                //$shape.popover('toggle');
            });

            $shape.on('mouseout', function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('filter');
                //***** For Mousing Out of the icon to hide the popup ********//
                //$shape.popover('toggle');
                $shape.popover('hide');
            });

            $shape.tooltip({
                container: "body",
                //title: props.title + ' - click to open/close'
            });

            var ImageOption = {
                placement: function (context, source) {
                    var position = $(source).position();
                    if (position.right > 500)
                        return "left";
                    if (position.left < 500)
                        return "right";
                    if (position.top < 300)
                        return "bottom";
                    return "top";
                },
                trigger: "manual",
                container: "html",
                html: true,
                content: '<img src="'+props.image_path+'"></img>'
            };

            var VideoOption = {
                placement: function (context, source) {
                    var position = $(source).position();
                    alert(position.left);
                    if (position.right > 500)
                        return "left";
                    if (position.left < 500)
                        return "right";
                    if (position.top < 300)
                        return "bottom";
                    return "top";
                },
                trigger: "manual",
                container: "html",
                html: true,
                content: '<video autoplay>' +
                '<source src="'+props.video_path+'" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
                '</video>'
            };

            if (props.eB_Image == "yes"){
                //alert("we have an image");
                $shape.popover(ImageOption);
            };

            if (props.eB_Video == "yes"){
                //alert("we have a video");
                $shape.popover(VideoOption);
            };
        });
    });
})(window.svgpublish);
```

Do you know why this may be happening? Is it because it takes a while to load the video and I should pre-load it?

I have been messing with this for almost 10 hours and I am not sure why this is acting like this.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have researched this issue and none of the solutions seem yo be working here.

Thank you.

Comment: My immediate instinct upon reading the title of your question is that you are trying to run an asynchronous operation synchronously.  But I don't see any promises.

Comment: Maybe your JS executes before your html is loaded?

Comment: Hi Amy. What do you mean about seeing any promises? I unfortunately am not a programmer and am using existing code to add some video.

Comment: Maybe the JS executes before the HTML is loaded but how come it works for the images and the text popups? That's what is mind boggling.

Comment: You should wrap everything with `$(document).ready(` rather than wrapping it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan did you mistype a word?  "you should wrap everything... rather than wrapping it" doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Mike, do you mean the first line where (function (diagram) { $(document).ready(function () { is and put the end } at the end? If so, that's how the code is.

Comment: @Amy Basically, everything should be contained in the `document.ready` handler, rather than having the `document.ready` handler wrapped inside the closure.

Comment: Also, seems a little odd to alias `window.svgpublish` as `diagram`, then use `window.svgpublish.diagramData`; why not just `diagram.diagramData`? I don't know what this `svgpublish` thing is either...

Comment: The svgpublish is because the page was created in Visio and exported to HTML with a 3rd party plugin that exports the pages as SVG. It is working but this one thing isn't.

Comment: Try placing the calls to `popover` inside a `setTimeout` and see if that makes it work.  eg.. `setTimeout(function () { $shape.popover(VideoOption);}, 1);`

Comment: @Keith, thanks for the tip. Where should I place it?

Comment: Where `$shape.popover(VideoOption);` is.

Comment: @ Keith, if you meant in place of $shape.popover(VideoOption);, nope that didn't work.... so strange.

Comment: it shows in the console so I know it's getting the value.